# Bulk Upload to Azure Storage using Secure connection

Tags: azure-storage, sftp, bulk-load

I need to upload files in batch to azure storage securely, and the files will be processed by an ADF pipeline later.

While I tried to upload files from my angular front-end to the API, the time taken to upload a large file took time ad my request was timing out.

Any suggestions as to how I can approach this problem better?